# Crear un objeto view de dos tablas diferentes usando entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Necesito devolver un `DataView` en la `Edit view` pero el view se llena de dos tablas diferentes.

Lo que necesito es saber como devolver un objeto `PatientView` de mis dos tablas, `patient` y `people`

Este es el Edit controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var patient = await _db.Patients.FindAsync(id);

            if (patient == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var person = await _db.People.FindAsync(patient.PersonId);

            if (person == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }     

         //in that place is that i need to send a PatientView
        return View(person);
    }
```

Este es el PatientView:

```
[NotMapped]
    public class PatientView: Person 
    {
        public int Record { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Seguro Principal")]
        public int InsuranceId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tipificacion Sanguinea")]
        public int BloodTypeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Edad")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        public string Age { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }  

    }
```

Esta es la tabla de personas:

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "El Campo es requerido")]
        [MaxLength(15, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "RNC/Cedula")]
        public string Rnc { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Campo es requerido")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Campo es requerido")]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Nacimiento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? BornDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genero")]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nivel Escolar")]
        public int? SchoolLevelId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nacionalidad")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
       // [Index("Person_Email_Index", IsUnique = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Correo")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
       // [Index("Person_Tel_Index", IsUnique = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Telefono")]
        public string Tel { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    //    [Index("Person_Cel_Index", IsUnique = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Celular")]
        public string Cel { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Estatus Marital")]
        public int MaritalSituationId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ocupacion")]
        public int OcupationId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Religion")]
        public int ReligionId { get; set; }

       // [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Campo es requerido")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "Direccion")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Estatus")]
        public int StatusId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
        [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
        public string Imagen { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Autor")]
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual MaritalSituation MaritalSituation { get; set; }
        public virtual Ocupation Ocupation { get; set; }
        public virtual Religion Religion { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
        public virtual SchoolLevel SchoolLevel { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }


    }
```

Esta es mi tabla de paciente:

```
  public class Patient
    {
        [Key]
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int Record { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fecha de Ingreso")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Seguro Principal")]
        public int InsuranceId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tipificacion Sanguinea")]
        public int BloodTypeId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Edad")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "La longitud maxima del campo es {1} caracteres")]
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
        public virtual BloodType BloodType { get; set; }
        public virtual Insurance Insurance { get; set; }
       }
```

This is the Create Post that I'm using, if you thing than theres something to improve

*Traducción: Esta es la vista para Create. Por si piensan que hay algo que mejorar:*

```
      public async Task<ActionResult> Create(PatientView view)
           {
                    var people = ToPeople(view);     
                    people.StatusId = 1;
                    _db.People.Add(people);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    var patient = ToPatient(view);
                    patient.PersonId = people.PersonId;                            
                    _db.Patients.Add(patient);    
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolvi de una manera similar a lo que propone Einer, cree un metodo que reciba dos variables de los tipos de mis tablas y arme la estructura

```
 private static PatientView ToView(Person pview, Patient view)
        {
            if (pview == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pview));
            return new PatientView()
            {
                PersonId = pview.PersonId,
                AuthorId = pview.AuthorId,
                Imagen = pview.Imagen,
                StatusId = pview.StatusId,
                Address = pview.Address,
                ReligionId = pview.ReligionId,
                OcupationId = pview.OcupationId,
                MaritalSituationId = pview.MaritalSituationId,
                Cel = pview.Cel,
                Tel = pview.Tel,
                Email = pview.Email,
                CountryId = pview.CountryId,
                GenderId = pview.GenderId,
                BornDate = pview.BornDate,
                LastName = pview.LastName,
                Name = pview.Name,
                Rnc = pview.Rnc,
                PatientId = view.PatientId,
                Record = view.Record,
                CreationDate = view.CreationDate,
                InsuranceId = view.InsuranceId,
                BloodTypeId = view.BloodTypeId,
                SchoolLevelId = pview.SchoolLevelId,
                Age=view.Age,
                FullName=pview.Name + " " + pview.LastName

            };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un join:

```
var personViewModel = (from person in _db.People
                       join patient in _db.Patients
                       on person.Id equals patient.PersonId

                      where person.Id = idPersona
                      select new PatientView{
                             Id = person.Id,
                             BloodTypeId = patient.BloodTypeId
                             //llena las demas propiedades del viewmodel con person y patient
                     }).ToList();
```

O haciendo 2 consultas:

```
var person = _db.People.Find(personId);
var patient = _db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.PersonId == personId);

var patienteViewModel = new PatientView{
 Id = person.Id,
 BloodTypeId = patient.BloodTypeId
 //llena las demas propiedades del viewmodel con person y patient
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de base para resolverlo de otra forma

Comment: Me alegra que te haya ayudado. Suerte!